# iOS - Autolayout using diferents iPhone Sizes

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

As you can see below I'm using autolayout but everything goes wrong if I've change from XR to SE.

I'm working within safe area but looks like is not enough.

Can anybody explain why?

I read about adaptative layout and vary for traits but looks like is done for size clases which is not this case because iphone xr and se has the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please show which constraints you have added to these views?

Comment: It seems like you are using a fixed width for the elements, work with leading and trailing spaces instead

Comment: Don't use the fixed height and width constraints, use the height and width constraints with multiplier according to the parent view then the over-lapping will not occur.

Comment: seems like you have given fixed height and width, use leading and trailing anchors with multiplier. It will be better if you show constraints you have added so we can tell you what the problem with it.